# Adding string comparison where clause to inner join takes huge performance hit with SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm playing around with Philadelphia transit data and I have an sqlite database storing the gtfs data. I have this query looking for departure times at a particular stop:

```
SELECT "stop_time".departure_time FROM "stop_time"
 INNER JOIN "trip" ON "trip".trip_id = "stop_time".trip_id 

 WHERE 

 (trip.route_id = '10726' ) 
 -- AND (trip.service_id = '1') 
 AND (stop_time.stop_id = '220') 
 AND (time( stop_time.departure_time ) > time('08:30:45')) 
 AND (time( stop_time.departure_time ) < time('09:30:45'));
```

The clause to match service_id to 1 is currently commented out.  If I run the query as it is now, without matching service_id, it takes 2 seconds.  If I uncomment the service_id clause, it'll take 30.  I'm clueless as to why since I'm already looking into the trip table for the route_id.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what indexes to you have on the tables?
have you tried EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN with and without the service_id ?

Comment: I'm not indexing anything, which would explain a lot.  I'm researching now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generally happens if an index is defined on (route_id, stop_id and departure_time) that is used when there is no filter on service_id. Once you include that in the `WHERE` clause, since it is not present in the index, it requires a `TABLE SCAN` and hence the shoot up in the execution time. If you include `service_id` also in the index definition, then `TABLE SCAN` would be replaced with `INDEX SCAN`.

Comment: I didn't have "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" defining my trip_id column in my trip column and was getting:  
  
0,0,1,SCAN TABLE trip (~10000 rows)
0,1,0,SEARCH TABLE stop_time USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (stop_id=? AND trip_id=?) (~7 rows)

After adding it, I get: 

0,0,0,SCAN TABLE stop_time (~25000 rows)
0,1,1,SEARCH TABLE trip USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?) (~1 rows)

and the performance issue disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have an index on `service_id` that is being chosen in preference to either another index, *and* there being not many different values of `service_id`, so using the index isn't being very useful because there are so many rows for `service_id = '1'`.